# Conditionally load script depending on current admin page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am using load to enqueue scripts only on my plugin page.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/

```
add_action("admin_menu", "sap_admin_menu");
function sap_admin_menu(){

    $menu = add_menu_page("Sticky Audio Player Player manager", "Sticky Audio Player", "manage_options", "sap_player_manager", "sap_player_manager_page", 'dashicons-playlist-audio');

    $submenu = add_submenu_page("sap_player_manager", "Sticky Audio Player Player manager", "Player manager", "manage_options", 'sap_player_manager', "sap_player_manager_page");   
    $submenu2 = add_submenu_page("sap_player_manager", "Sticky Audio Player Playlist manager", "Playlist manager", "manage_options", 'sap_playlist_manager', 'sap_playlist_manager_page');

    add_action( 'load-' . $menu, 'sap_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
    add_action( 'load-' . $submenu, 'sap_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
    add_action( 'load-' . $submenu2, 'sap_admin_enqueue_scripts' );

}
```

This works well, however I would like to know how to detect on which page I am currently so  I can enqueue different scripts in sap_admin_enqueue_scripts function:

```
function sap_admin_enqueue_scripts() {

    //I need to detect page here

    if ( is_page( 'sap_player_manager' ) ) {//this doesnt work


    }
```

I tried using is_page but I cant make it work.

Comment: `is_page` is a frontend function, and works off of the main query

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menus' ); 

function my_admin_menus() {
   $GLOBALS['my_page'] = add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', 
   MY_ADMIN_CAPABILITY, 'menu-slug', 'show_page_content');
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_js');

function enqueue_admin_js($hook) {
  if($GLOBALS['my_page'] === $hook) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
    // Isn't it nice to use dependencies and the already registered core js files?
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', INCLUDES_URI . '/js/my_script.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-tabs' ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's great to use the action-hook argument but I would not use a global here, why not use the result of var_dump( $hook ), there is very very very little chance you need to change that slug later. Seems acceptable to me to use it as a simple string in if condition.

Answer (score 1):

What about [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)?

```
$screen = get_current_screen();

if ( 'sap_player_manager' === $screen->id ) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

look into  [`get_current_screen();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen)

Some notes from codex:

> This function is defined on most admin pages, but not all. Thus there are cases where `is_admin()` will return true, but attempting to call `get_current_screen()` will result in a fatal error because it is not defined. One known example is wp-admin/customize.php.

There is also a [`current_screen`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/current_screen) hook for a different approach.

Both make available a `WP_Screen`. in example:

```
WP_Screen Object {
    ["action"] => string(0) ""
    ["base"] => string(4) "post"
    ["columns":"WP_Screen":private] => int(0)
    ["id"] => string(12) "someposttype"
    ["in_admin":protected] => string(4) "site"
    ["is_network"] => bool(false)
    ["is_user"] => bool(false)
    ["parent_base"] => NULL
    ["parent_file"] => NULL
    ["post_type"] => string(12) "someposttype"
    ["taxonomy"] => string(0) ""
    ["_help_tabs":"WP_Screen":private] => array(0) { }
    ["_help_sidebar":"WP_Screen":private] => string(0) ""
    ["_options":"WP_Screen":private] => array(0) { }
    ["_show_screen_options":"WP_Screen":private] => NULL
    ["_screen_settings":"WP_Screen":private] => NULL
}
```